# How can I make my local Elasticsearch which is running on my system make it available to be accessible from anywhere? Is this possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, xampp, filezilla

I have windows 10 machine where I have XAMPP server installed and running.
I also have Elasticsearch running on the same machine at HTTPS://{machineIP}:9200 with elasticssearch.yml setting of the network host to 0.0.0.0

But I am unable to access this HTTPS://{machineIP}:9200 from any other machine.

Can anyone please help me - do I have to do a XAMPP-FileZilla FTP server set for elastic-search apis running on my machine to become accessible from anywhere?

Comment: what do your Elasticsearch logs show, from startup?

Comment: It is just as a normal elastic search starts and runs- no errors or exceptions. I can reach elastic search locally on my computer with https://localhost:9200 or https://IP-Address:9200

I think I need to get my computer IP address become reachable from anywhere - may be this what is needed but I dont know how to do.

Comment: please share your logs